# How can I use wildcards with IF -contains on an array?

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script backing up the schema for a database to a version control system. I just realized that replicated objects are being scripted out as well; these objects start with sp_MSupd_, sp_MSdel_, sp_MSins_, and syncobj_0x. I would like to skip these items.

I know I can do something like this:

```
$ExcludeObjectNames = @("sp_MSupd_", "sp_MSdel_","sp_MSins_","syncobj_0x")
If ($ExcludeObjectNames -contains "sp_MSdel_SampleObject")
{
    Write-Host "replicated item found"
}
```

But this only works for exact matches. I tried adding * to the elements in the array but that did not work. And I know I can use -like, but that seems to only be for single values, not arrays.

I know I can do this

```
$ObjectNames = "sp_MSdel_SampleObject"
If ($ObjectNames -like "sp_MSupd_*" -OR $ObjectNames -like "sp_MSdel_*" -OR $ObjectNames -like "sp_MSins_*" -OR $ObjectNames -like "syncobj_0x*")
{
    Write-Host "replicated item found"
}
```

This is well and fine, BUT if I find more and more things to omit, this becomes more and more ugly.

Is there a way to use wildcards with -contains on an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ExcludeObjectNames = @("sp_MSupd_", "sp_MSdel_","sp_MSins_","syncobj_0x")

Foreach ($ExcludeObjectName in $ExcludeObjectNames) {
  If ("sp_MSdel_SampleObject" -match $ExcludeObjectName)
  {
      Write-Host "replicated item found"
  }
}
```

Or if you only want to edit variables in the script, you can do:

```
$ExcludeObjectNames = @("sp_MSupd_", "sp_MSdel_","sp_MSins_","syncobj_0x")
$ObjectToCheck = "sp_MSdel_SampleObject" # This variable contains your original contains target

Foreach ($ExcludeObjectName in $ExcludeObjectNames) {
  If ($ObjectToCheck -match $ExcludeObjectName)
  {
      Write-Host "replicated item found"
  }
}
```

If you don't like looping, you can just build a regex filter from your original array:

```
$ExcludeObjectNames = @("sp_MSupd_", "sp_MSdel_","sp_MSins_","syncobj_0x")
$ObjectToCheck = "sp_MSdel_SampleObject" # This variable contains your original contains target
$excludeFilter = '(^' + ($excludeobjectnames -join "|^") + ')' # Regex filter that you never have to manually update

If ($ObjectToCheck -match $ExcludeFilter)
{
    Write-Host "replicated item found"
}
```

Comment: I do like the regex option as I don't need the loop a set a variable to know to skip extracting the object to a file.

Comment: FYI, without using carets as so '(^' + ($excludeobjectnames -join "|^") + ')', you get substring matches as well.

Comment: I added the carets since it seems that you will always know the beginning characters of your excludes. Thanks

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean A warning though. If ever one of the words to check has characters that have special meaning in regex, like `*` or a backslash, this won't work. Better make a habit of performing a `[regex]::Escape()` on each of these words before joining them with the pipe symbol `|`.

Comment: @Theo Since the object names are turned into file names in my script, I eliminate invalid characters before I get to a point where I need to compare them :)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Up to you, but [special regex characters](https://regular-expressions.mobi/refcharacters.html?wlr=1) is a different thing as invalid filename characters.